# Measurability of Modulus

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

*Context: This problem came up while reading an essay on Bochner integrability.*

---

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space and $E$ a Banach space.

Consider two plain functions $f:\Omega\to E$ and $g:\Omega\to E$. Then:
$$\|f\|,\|g\|\text{ measurable}\implies\|f+g\|\text{ measurable}$$
Can you give me a hint how to prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not true. Consider

$$
f = \chi_V - \chi_{V^c},
$$

where $V$ is a nonmeasurable set and let $g \equiv 1$.

Then $\Vert f \Vert \equiv 1$ is measurable (the same holds for $g$), but

$$
\Vert f+g \Vert = f + g
$$

is not measurable.

Comment: Hmm ok ...but how can one prove then linearity of the Bochner integral? (Should I better open an extra thread on this?)

Comment: For linearity of the Bochner integral, you assume that $f,g$ are (Bochner) measurable (not only $\Vert f \Vert$ and $\Vert g \Vert$). Then also $f+g$ is measurable and hence so is $\Vert f+g \Vert$.

Comment: Again back to the problem here: Your example makes perfectly sense that is though both expressions are measurable themselve the combined expression is not measurable. But on the other hand knowing that they're measurable and positive gives rise to monoton sequences of simple functions $s_n\uparrow\|f\|$ and $t_n\uparrow\|g\|$ and thus also $s_n+t_n\uparrow\|f+g\|$ showing that $\|f+g\|$ is indeed measurable... So there must be a flaw in that argumentation. But where??

Comment: From $s_n \uparrow \Vert f \Vert$ and $t_n \uparrow \Vert g \Vert$, it does **not** follow that $s_n + t_n \uparrow \Vert f + g\Vert$, only $s_n + t_n \uparrow \Vert f \Vert + \Vert g \Vert$.

Comment: But don't you have $0\leq\|f+g\|-s_n-t_n\leq\|f\|+\|g\|-s_n-t_n\to 0$?

Comment: Ah I forgot that not necessarily $\|f+g\|-s_n-t_n\geq 0$... Thanks anyway :)